# Titan SMTP mail configuration failed PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, smtp, hosting

I have a problem with SMTP sending mail on the hosting website in Titan; I get this response.

> Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 5.7.1
> hello@example.com: Sender address rejected: not owned by user
> info@mmcollection.dk

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=MMCollection
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.titan.email
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@mmcollection.dk
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

In addition, I checked the username and the password, and they are valid. Also, I've changed the encryption to SSL/TLS and changed the port to 465 and 587, but it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by changing the port and adding the from address (with quotes).

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.titan.email
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=your@email.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="your@email.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use a different port combination: (465,SSL)/(587,STARTTLS)/(25,None)